# Stopping inheritance without using final

Tags: java, inheritance

Is there any other method of stopping inheritance of a class apart from declaring it as final or by declaring its constructor as private?

Comment: What's wrong with final?

Comment: could you try to explain why you are trying to avoid the use of the final keyword?

Comment: Probably because there's a framework involved that creates subclasses.

Comment: i was just trying to find some other ways... they produce interesting results.. I was just curious

Comment: ...in which case, there's no way to stop inheritance that also allows inheritance. :-)

Comment: @dtsazza There are things a framework could do that you'd normally not let user code do; a framework could change the protection level of a private constructor at run-time. AFIK you cannot mess with final though...

Comment: @dtsazza In effect the framework could have the "dont do this at home, kids" attitude.

Comment: Why is that everyone is answering: "Use final" when the question it self says "Other than final..." I think they are right, but the point is, that is not the question. I guess we are getting use to "subjective & argumentative" questions that we are missing the point.

Comment: The question is very clear, and the answer are not real answer, and yet getting upvoted. Shouldn't we use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318503/comments-for-comments-answers-for-answers-is-it-that-hard  :)

Comment: is this a interview/classroom questions?

Comment: There are plenty of valid reasons for avoiding final, mostly when you are extending a framework who's methods and constructors don't allow final.  App server extensions come to mind.

Answer (score 34):

A comment

```
//Do not inherit please
```

Comment: I actually believe that's the best solution ever. You could even describe why it shouldn't to be inherited from.

Answer (score 24):

Two more options:

- make each method final, so people can't override them. You avoid accidental calling of methods from subclass this way. This doesn't stop subclassing though.
- put check into constructor for class:

  ```
  if (this.getClass() != MyClass.class) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Subclasses not allowed");
  }
  ```

  Then nobody will be able to instantiate subclass of your class.

(Not that I suggest using these techniques, it just came to my mind. I would use final class and/or private constructor)

Comment: Rats, I was just going to post the exception one myself.

Comment: Except if the finalize method is overriden, the instance can be recovered.

Comment: +1 I didn't think there would be a real answer to this question, but I guess this is as close as you're going to get.

Comment: @Chris Lively: Constructor from super class must always be called. You can 'override' constructor (there is no such thing as overriding constructor though, as constructor is not inherited), but you cannot 'skip' constructor from super class.

Answer (score 9):

- Use final
- Use private constructors
- Use a comment:

  ```
  // do not inherit
  ```
- Use a javadoc comment
- Make every method final, so people can't override them
- Use a runtime check in the class constructor:

  ```
  if (this.getClass() != MyClass.class) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Subclasses not allowed");
  }
  ```

Comment: The comment idea really does not make much sense.  A JavaDoc comment makes a lot more sense, but is still not foolproof.

Comment: [Java doesn't prevent sub-classing of class with private constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662680/2114786)

Answer (score 7):

Final was created to solve this problem.

Comment: The question says, without using final

Answer (score 4):

Make your constructors private and provide factory functions to create instances.

This can be especially helpful when you want to choose an appropriate implementation from multiple, but don't want to allow arbitrary subclassing as in

```
abstract class Matrix {
   public static Matrix fromDoubleArray(double[][] elemens) {
     if (isSparse(elements)) {
      return new SparseMatrix(elements);
    } else {
      return new DenseMatrix(elements);
    }
  }
  private Matrix() { ... }  // Even though it's private, inner sub-classes can still use it
  private static class SparseMatrix extends Matrix { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `final` is the canonical way.

```
public final class FinalClass {
  // Class definition
}
```

If you want to prevent individual methods from being overridden, you can declare them as final instead. (I'm just guessing here, as to why you would *want* to avoid making the whole class final.)

Comment: Reasons similar to java.lang.String, I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say it's typically bad form.  Though there are almost always cases where something is valid, I'd have to saying stopping inheritance in an OO world is normally not a good idea.  Read up on the [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/05/28/the-open-closed-principle-on-msdn.aspx).  Protect your functionality but don't make it impossible for the guy who comes in and supports it...

Comment: Inheritance is way overrated. Unless you design your class for subclassing, you better avoid it.

Comment: +1, I'm betting that Uncle Bob Martin knows more about OO than just about anyone here.

Comment: +1 to Peter's comment. As I've said elsewhere (many times!) I wish classes were sealed (C#) / final (Java) by default. Inheritance is great, when you really need it - but it can be a pain if you just use it without thinking carefully about it.

Comment: "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it." -- Josh Bloch, Effective Java Item 17

Comment: Read Michael Feather's book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code".  It's gotten me through a number of brownfield projects and things like classes and methods you can't touch are major pain points.  Even if you didn't intend for it, feature XYZ will need it.  All about future proofing...

Comment: @Mark G: Inheritance restricts changes in implementation, so I don't regard allowing it as future-proofing at all. It *limits* future changes rather than allowing them.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I guess in my experience I've just not seen it.  Take any of the dialogs in the .NET BCL (Open/Save/Print), can't do a danged thing with them because they're sealed, major pain.  But this discussion should probably be in a different question with the tag of 'Subjective'

Answer (score 0):

Without using a final class, you can basically make all the constructors private:

```
public class A {
    private A() {} //Overriding default constructor of Java
}
```

Which although will also make this class abstract-ish by disallowing creating an object of this class, yet as any inheritance requires `super();` in the constructor, and because the constructor is private, a compilation error will be the maximum you can get when one tries to inherit that class.
Yet, I would recommend using final instead as it is less code and includes the option of creating objects.