# how to avoid the inheritance to our class without using final keyword?

Tags: java, class

```
class a
{
----
}
class b extends a
{

}
```

But my class a not inherited into b how

Comment: What behavior are you expecting, and what are you seeing?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `final` keyword?  That's specifically what the `final` keyword _does_.

Comment: @David Yes, it's a bit like asking how to make a field static without using the `static` keyword. It's doable but why?

Comment: @biziclop: It tangentially reminds me of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4464291/328193  Just an odd use of the language, and makes me think that there's something _behind_ the question that we're not seeing.  Like the OP is trying to solve a higher-level problem and needs to step back for a moment to actually solve it, instead of trying to get SO to help with the current attempted "solution."

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451182/stopping-inheritance-without-using-final

Comment: @David or this was an interview question to test the applicant's knowledge of the programming language.

Comment: @Jesper: Ah, could be. And interview questions _always_ make me wonder what is the core reason behind it, because they're _always_ contrived and have no core reason :)  So many times I've wanted to hear a candidate say, "Why would you even do it that way?"

Answer (score 9):

What exactly is your question? How to prevent class `a` from being subclassed, but without making class `a` `final`?

Make all constructors of class `a` `private`. Provide a factory method for creating instances of `a`.

```
class a {
    // Private constructor
    private a() {
    }

    // Factory method
    public static a createA() {
        return new a();
    }
}
```

Comment: its  wow .. I've learnt something new today :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use following in your class constructor :

```
if (this.getClass() != A.class) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Subclassing not allowed");
}
```

But using this way, you will restrict inheritance at run time.

Comment: Note though that this isn't a 100% safe method. If someone **really** wants to instantiate a subclass of A, they will be able to.